# How to find a certain class using .find() or some jQuery Syntax?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
if( hasWhiteSpace($(this).find(".nospace:input").val()) ){
    $(this).find(".nospace:input").filter(function() {
        return hasWhiteSpace(this.value) == true;
    }).addClass("blank");
    setError(".motd_register_company","There must be no space in between.");
    return false;
}
```

There is something wrong about my code above, and the code only validate the first input, while the others not, how could I validate all the "nospace" class that I have in my form?

can you guys trim my code if there is something wrong.

Comment: Your question does not make sense.

Comment: Use jsfiddle to give us a look.

Comment: @MДΓΓБДLL. So as his code... **:(**

Comment: @mozillanerd sir this is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/XeqVv/2/

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to recursively search elements for a particular classname?  If so:

```
$('input.class_name').each(function() {
    // Do you stuff to this input element
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery.each("input.nospace", function(i, el){
  var self = $(el);

  if(hasWhiteSpace(self.val()) self.addClass("blank");

});
```